# Javascript click doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm simply trying to figure out how to automatically click the login button. Nothing I've tried works.

https://www.24option.com/24option/#Trade

I've tried:

```
$(".loginButton").click()
$("#loginButton").click()
$(".gwt-PushButton.loginButton.gwt-PushButton-up").click()
```

I've also tried using a few "click simulators" via javascript. Those didn't work either.

Any ideas how to just get the button to click via JS?

Comment: Use: `$('.login_btn').click();`.

Comment: That's what I meant. Sorry. It doesn't work.

Comment: Basically you want it to auto-click once the form has been filled?

Comment: Yes. I can fill the form in and I can also "submit" the form but I need to actually click the button not submit the form. The reason for this is because once logged in, the button becomes a logout button and there is no longer a form. Solving for clicking the LOGIN button also solves for clicking the LOGOUT button.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
$('.loginButton').on('click', function () {
    //code here
});
```

Comment: It's not my site. I'm trying to automate using the site.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#TopPanel").find("#loginForm").submit();
```

but if you need only the click

```
$("#TopPanel").find("#loginForm").find('button').click();
```

After the las edit I think I'll give up, but if you want to keep trying I add this (in case real clicks are being detected somehow, play around with the coordinates or something)

```
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
document.getElementById("loginButton").parentNode.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, however, I'm trying to click the button, not submit the form. Once logged in, the button turns to a logout button and is no longer a form and I need to be able to click the logout button as well. So I'm trying to figure out how to trigger the click on the LOGIN button. There has to be a way...

Comment: Check the edit and let me know if it works once inside the site

Comment: Nope, and when trying it on the main page I get:
TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of null

Comment: Well, the click works outside the site (tested on chrome console), I can't test it as a logged user, but it may be the same thing, find the button locating a parent who has an id and then click it

Comment: Ah, sorry. https://www.24option.com/24option/#Trade - try that. Nothing will click that login button.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work. I really do appreciate your efforts though!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$('.login_btn').click();
```

or

```
$('.login_btn').trigger('click');
```

Comment: But the OP didn't ask for performance. They do same thing in this context, I guess: if `click()` doesn't work, `trigger("click")` does not work, too.

Comment: @JanusP on https://www.24option.com/24option/#Login use `$('.grayButton').click();`

Comment: @TusharGupta - that isn't the same page I need. I need the LOGIN button up top (as the internal logout button works the same).

$('.login_btn').trigger('click') does nothing, same with click().

Answer (score 0):

Can you show more code? It works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kZMyA/):

```
var btn = document.getElementById("button");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){ alert("button clicked"); });
btn.click();
```

Maybe you're having an error with DOM Selection. If you are, try using FireBug or the developer console in Chrome to catch it.

Comment: All the code is on the site listed. If you use chrome console or firebug you can see nothing works to click the button.

Answer (score 0):

define the click function

```
$("#loginButton").click(function(){


  alert("clicked");

});
```

trigger the click function , inside document.ready function

```
$('#loginButton').trigger('click');
```

then the button wil be clicked automatically.